# Right Click Change Background wallpaper not Working [Ubuntu 13.10]

Tags: desktop-background

Just installed Ubuntu 13.10 just a couple of days ago, everything was running fine, till one flaw or bug is irritating me. Right click "Change Background Wallpaper" is not working and instead settings window is getting open.

suggest me some ways to overcome this issue.

Comment: Change background is done in the "Appearance" settings inside the "System settings". When right clicking to "Change Desktop Background" it should go to System Settings > Appearance.

Is this what you experience, or does it only go to System Settings and not taking the next step?

Comment: I also experience the same in Ubuntu 13.10. It won't go to "Appearance", it just displays Settings.

Comment: For me there's no "Appearance" any more in "System settings". What package is it in?

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this probs too. wallpaper just suddenly weren't showing up no matter what i changed into, although, the logon wall paper seems to change to my choosing...  if you have compiz installed, go to utility -> click on wallpaper -> remove the current set background picture... what ever you previous change your wallpaper too should appear as background...  and you should be able to change your background to your desire...  hope this help